# pagination ruby on rails with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey guys I am trying to implement pagination using the `will_paginate` gem, and it doesn't seem to be working. I have added the gem to my `Gemfile` and tried the code below:

**controller**

```
 def team_search  
   @teams = CareTeam.all.order('created_at ASC').paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 10)
 end
```

**view**

```
    <h1>Search for a team</h1>
    <p>search for a team by team name</p>
    <%= form_tag search_team_results_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: 
      "Search Teams By name", required: true %>
     <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
   <% end %>

   <%= will_paginate @teams %>
```

**model**

```
   def self.search(team_name)
      if team_name
        team_name.downcase!
        self.where('LOWER(team_name) LIKE ?', "%#{team_name}%").order('created_at ASC')
      else
        CareTeam.all.order('created_at ASC')
       end
    end
```

When I navigate to my view, nothing shows up. Does anyone analyse from above what could be wrong?

Comment: When you say "nothing shows up" do you mean just the part where you call `will_paginate "teams"` or the entire view in general?

Comment: just the part where i call the will_paginate function the rest of the view renders fine

Comment: Have you tried running the query in the rails console:

`CareTeam.all.order('created_at ASC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)`

Replace `params[:page]` with what is being passed in by the controller.

Comment: Yes i ran it and return "undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object"

Comment: Sorry, made a ninja edit, replace `params[:page]` with what is being passed in by the controller.

Comment: how would i know whats being passed in by the controller ? im a little confused

Comment: SOLVED will paginate assumes there are more than 1 records in your DB, i created more records and it works fine

Comment: will_paginate works fine with no records, one records or more than one records, so your "SOLVED" is accidental and nothing to do with the number of records.